# Disable auto-instrumented request at Application insights getting logged from Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-6.0, azure-application-insights

We are using azure function with .Net 6 isolated. We are also using application insights with this azure function. In trigger we are using custom TelemetryClient inside our implementation.

We are noticing for one invocation of trigger at application insights in request table we are getting 2 request logged.

Screenshot : [image]

I want to disable auto-generated request from azure function.
i tried adding the below configuration.

```
"ApplicationInsights": {
"EnableRequestTrackingTelemetryModule": false }
```

But this did not resolve the problem.
I'm using the autofac.

Program.cs-

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(SetConfigurationSource)
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory()).ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>((context, containerBuilder) =>
    {
        containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new Module1(context.Configuration));
        containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new Module2(iotHubConnectionConfiguration));
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) => ConfigureServices(services, context.Configuration))
    .Build();            
await host.RunAsync();
```

Please help me how I can disable this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your `Program.cs`,Function code  and `.csproj` files

Comment: I'm using the autofac.

Comment: When I tried to AddApplicationTelemetryService() HostBuilder started throwing exception.